# How to retrieve multiple values in Firebase Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm a beginner in Firebase and I'm still learning so I made an login-signup app and I'm adding more functionality like Saving Data(which is done) and now I can't figure out how I will retrieve multiple data with different User UID's

Heres a screenshot of my database
[image]

I would like to retrieve all of the data here in 3 different edittext in the layout basically when a person logs in, the program should read database and check if there is data in there then it will get data from the database otherwise it will show a toast saying that No data saved to retrieve... I would be really thankfull if anyone helps me out with this...

Comment: You seem to have tried something already. If you're stuck writing code, post the [minimal, complete code that reproduces where you're stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register callacks for Firebase data.

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("<your-firebase-app-url>").child("<node-name-to-observe>");
ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener(){
        @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            // save to sqlite       
        }

         @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

}

        @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
}
});
```

This is a async call. You need to save it to local db like Sqlite and use it from there. Callbacks of ChildEventListener will be called multiple times based on number of child nodes present.

Comment: this answer is about saving I need to retrieve data

Comment: This answer is about *retrieving* data. I recommend giving it a try and reading the [Firebase documentation about reading and writing data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write).